# Using index value inside of a Handlebars each block

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, indexing, handlebars.js

I have a Handlebars template that inserts an `img` element on my page. The image URLs come from an array that can have *up to* 8 items, but I only want to insert the first 4.

A simple `{{#each}}` block like this inserts an `img` for every item:

```
{{#each items}}
    <img src="{{item.url}}" />
{{/each}}
```

How do I "stop" the `{{#each}}` after the first 4 items? Or, put another way, how do I tell it to only insert the `img` element if its index in the array is less than 4 (0 through 3)?

I know I can *output* the current index with `{{@index}}`, but I can't seem to use that within an `{{#if}}` block. In other words, this doesn't work:

```
{{#each items}}
    {{#if {{@index}} < 4}}
    <img src="{{item.url}}" />
    {{/if}}
{{/each}}
```

What do I do instead?

Answer (score 2):

I think the simplest way would be to slice your array, `.slice(0, 4)`, *before* you pass it to your compiled template function.

But if, for some reason, that is not an option, I suppose you would have to create a custom helper:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('firstFour', function (context, options) {
    var result = '';
    var length = Math.min(context.length, 4);
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        result += options.fn(context[i]);
    }

    return result;
});
```

And your template would look like this:

```
{{#firstFour items}}
    <img src="{{this.url}}" />
{{/firstFour}}
```